# Entity Framework Linq set property of an object without additional projection by SELECT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, inheritance, select

I'm implementing an inheritance scenario with Entity Framework 6. Inheritance only exists on DTO level, i.e. i have two classes `Foo` and `Bar : Foo`, 
I have  first method that selects an `IQueryable<Foo>` and then several methods that select additional properties for specific inheriting classes like Bar.

Normally,  I would have code like

```
from foo in SelectFoo()
join barAdditionalProps in .....    
select new Bar{
    Id = foo.Id,
    Description = foo.Description,
    Baz = barAdditionalProps.Baz}
```

which would give a nice single SQL query as a result.

This, unfortunately, means that all properties from foo will have to be copied during second projection (first one is inside `SelectFoo`). In real life code that would mean 20+ properties copied in every method using `SelectFoo`.

I would like to do something like this (code is prepared in LINQPad, assume `this` == EFContext):

```
void Main()
{      
    (from barBase in SelectT<Bar>()
     join field in this.Fields on barBase.Id equals field.ProductId
     let _1 = barBase.Baz = field.Baz // this part fails with exception
                                      // An expression tree may not contain an assigment operator         
     select barBase)
    .First()
    .Dump();      
}

public IQueryable<T> SelectT<T>() where T : Foo, new() 
{
    return this
           .Products
           .Select(x => new T
           {
                 Id = x.Id,
                 Description = x.Description
           });
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public int Baz {get;set;}
}
```

Receiving the exception described above, I'm looking for a way to make this work or any other solution that would allow me not to copy all base class properties during second projection.

Comment: You should join the original queries and project the result to the DTOs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have one Foo, that contains navigation properties to the other parts, and the `.Include` as necessary?

Comment: @Gert Arnold, but that would mean I'll have to copy projection of the original Foo in every method, i.e 3x same 20 lines of code? Robert McKree, not sure what you mean. The query producing this DTOs uses 7-20 tables totaling over 50 columns only about 30 of which are used. The DTOs are POCOs, not Entities.

Comment: It depends on what happens in `SelectFoo()`, really. If it return an `IQueryable` that's still connected to the EF query provider you should still be able to use in in other LINQ statements and projections that will only select the properties that are requested.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, that is the point, i'm interested in 20 properties of the original Foo and I don't wont to repeat the code copying them in every method that uses SelectFoo().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no existing tools were up to the job, I wrote my own library that uses expression tree modification to project baseclass dto in subclass dto automatically.

Now instead of this

```
     IQueryable<BaseDto> baseQuery = GetBaseQuery();

  IQueryable<SubclassDto> query = from baseDto in baseQuery
                                  let moreData = DataContext.vMoreData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == baseDto.Id)
                                  select new SubclassDto()
                                  {
                                    NewProp1 = moreData.Foo,
                                    NewProp2 = moreData.Baz,
                                    OldProp1 = moreData.SomeOverridingData,

                                    OldProp2 = baseDto.OldProp2,
                                    OldProp3 = baseDto.OldProp3,
                                    OldProp4 = baseDto.OldProp4,
                                    //... 20 more projections from BaseDto to SubclassDto
                                  };
```

We have this

```
 IQueryable<BaseDto> baseQuery = GetBaseQuery();

 IQueryable<SubclassDto> query = from baseDto in baseQuery                                  
                                 let moreData = DataContext.vMoreData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == baseDto.Id) 
                                 select baseDto.AutoProjectInto(() => new SubclassDto()
                                 {
                                  NewProp1 = moreData.Foo,
                                  NewProp2 = moreData.Baz,
                                  OldProp1 = moreData.SomeOverridingData
                                 });

 IQueryable<SubclassDto> activateQuery = query.ActivateAutoProjects();
```

And all properties that were not bound by the SubclassDto initialization are projected from baseDto automatically.

Library is available via Github https://github.com/IKoshelev/Linq.AutoProject and NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Linq.AutoProject